# Добавить строки из одной таблицы в другую [НЕ ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ]

Tags: mysql

Имеются три таблицы с пользователями.
У всех трёх таблиц есть `user_id` , его я и хочу получить из этих всёх трёх таблиц.

Нужно взять из каждой таблицы этот `user_id` , чтобы он был в одну колонну, и просто слепить все три таблицы в одну.

```
SELECT `userdatabase`.`user_id`, `steamdatabase`.`user_id` FROM `userdatabase` LEFT JOIN `steamdatabase` ON `userdatabase`.`user_id` = `steamdatabase`.`user_id`
```

Выводит лишь :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А столбец с `user_id` должен быть один и к нему вниз должно добавиться значение из второй таблицы.

Comment: Три селекта с Union / union all между ними?

Comment: @PashaPash , не очень понял о чём вы. Раньше не работал с подобными запросами, делал выборку из таблицы, но не вот такое сложение трёх таблиц в одну с одним ключом.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html сорри,  не получается написать полноценный ответ с телефона.

Comment: @PashaPash , добавьте пожалуйста ваш ответ, выберу его как правильный, это то что нужно, всё получилось!

Comment: Не могу -  с телефона нереально :) можете  запостить ответ от своего имени,  со ссылкой на документацию и окончательным кодом,  который у вас получился?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большая благодарность пользователю @PashaPash , за быстрый ответ об UNION.

Действительно , это помогло решить мой нелепый вопрос.
Вот готовый рабочий код :

```
   (SELECT `user_id` FROM `userdatabase`) 
    UNION 
   (SELECT `user_id` FROM `steamdatabase`) 
    UNION 
   (SELECT `user_id` FROM `vkdatabase`);
```

[dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

Ссылка на офф источник.

Ещё раз, большое спасибо!